# Mass 301 Redirects for IIS product39/user-manual.html > product39/user-manual/

Tags: redirect, iis

What is the best way to implement Mass 301 Redirects for IIS to move only pages that end in .html to the page name folder for many pages in a large site? I am using Windows Server 2016.

For example:

product56/download.html > product56/download/

product56/user-manual.html > product56/user-manual/

However, if index.html is specified it should not redirect to the folder, but the root, for example:

product47/index.html > product47/

And then I also have 300 or so individual aspx pages that need to redirect to custom URLs, for example:

cart/Label-Software-P590.aspx > products/label-software/niceware/

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you could use IIS url rewrite to achieve your requirement, you could download it from this [url](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite).

> product56/download.html > product56/download/
>   product56/user-manual.html > product56/user-manual/

Url rewrite contains the friendly url, you could use it to achieve your requirement. Details you could refer to this article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/user-friendly-url-rule-template

For the specified html, you should write the custom url by yourself.

For example:

> product47/index.html > product47/

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="inde" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="product47/index.html" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://yourdomian/product47/" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

> cart/Label-Software-P590.aspx > products/label-software/niceware/

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="inde2x" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="cart/Label-Software-P590.aspx" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://yourdomian/products/label-software/niceware/" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```